# Arrangement of two string charecters into one string using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, algorithm, loops

I have two string which should be put together into one string. First string is a input value and second string is a pattern how the first string should look.
 Here is the example - 
 Input string( var val ) - **9165678823** 
 Patter string( var mask ) - **(999)999-9999**
 Output string should look like( var startVal ) - **(916)567-8823**
 I have tried working out and this is my code

```
            var val = $(control).data("loadMaskValue"); // Input Value
            var mask = $(control).attr("mask");         //Masking Pattern
            var startVal = "";
            var j = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
                    var c = mask.charAt(j);
                    if (c == '9' || c == 'X' || c == 'A') {    //Checks the char is normal char 
                        startVal += val.charAt(j);
                    }
                    else {
                        startVal += c;                      //Inserts the special char to string like ( ) -
                        startVal += val.charAt(j);
                    }
                    j = startVal.length;
                }
```

The problem with this code is it misses one number in between. The result of this code is 
 startValue - **(965)688-2**.
 PLease help me.

Comment: Can't you just parse the input and construct a new string? Go over the input and when i==0 add a `(` and when i==2 add a `)`.

Comment: The pattern can be dynamic. you cannot hardcode values for i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler implementation:

```
var input = '9165678823';
var mask = '(999)999-9999';

var output = '';
var offset = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
    var char = mask.charAt(i);

    if ('9XA'.indexOf(char) != -1) {
        output += input.charAt(i - offset);
    } else {
        output += mask.charAt(i);
        offset += 1;
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

​Make sure that `input` has been stripped of all whitespace at the beginning and end.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qWtjk/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to take the elements out. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/9MmqS/

    <strike>var str= '9165678823';
    var regEx = new RegExp("(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})");</strike>

```
var m = regEx.exec(str);
var res = '(' + m[1] + ')' + m[2] + '-' + m[3];
console.log(res);
```

result is **(916)567-8823**

UPDATE: How to make this work with a dynamic pattern. Check updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/9MmqS/

```
$(function() {
    var str= '9165678823';
    var regEx = new RegExp("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})");

    var m = regEx.exec(str);
    var mask = "({0}){1}-{2}";
    var res = mask.supplant(m.slice(1));
    console.log(res);
});​
```

Using supplant method from here: http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html

Once you understand your regular expression, you can make this work with any pattern and mask.

Comment: I guess this will not work, as masks can have different formats.

Comment: You could also just use replacement: `'9165678823'.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, '($1)$2-$3');`

Comment: @BhuddhiP, the Pattern string is dynamic and it cannot be static with separator char like this "(", ")" and this "-"

Comment: @ShishirKumarM, Check how this can be done with a dynamic pattern. I'll make it work with any number of matches too. Using a loop for this kind of functionality is poor in performance.

Comment: @Blender, true that. Good point. But I prefer using the supplant method (which I added later), because it looks more clear, at least for this scenario.